# Unable to set additional environment variable in Gatsby build

Tags: environment-variables, gatsby

I am trying to build Gatsby project with staging environment variable but it is always using production environment variables

I used this tutorial [Environment Variables | Gatsby](https://v1.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/#environment-variables)

This is my gatsby-config.js file

```
let activeEnv = process.env.ACTIVE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV || 
'development';

console.log(`Using environment config: '${activeEnv}'`);

require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${activeEnv}`,
});

module.exports = { 
plugins: [
   {
     resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
     options: {
       precision: 8,
     },
   },
 ]
};
```

This is the command i am using to build

```
"build:staging": "set ACTIVE_ENV='staging' && gatsby build",
```

When i run the above command it show **Using environment config: 'staging'**
but after build it uses production variables

My .env files [image: .env files]

> After Running **ACTIVE_ENV='staging' gatsby build** i got this
>
> ```
> $ ACTIVE_ENV='staging' gatsby build
> success delete html and css files from previous builds — 0.058 s
> ⠁ Using environment config: 'staging'
> { API_URL: 'https://api.company.com/api/company/test',
>   COMPANY_URL: 'https://company.test.com/test/' }
> success open and validate gatsby-config — 0.011 s
> info One or more of your plugins have changed since the last time you ran 
> Gatsby. As a precaution, we're deleting your site's cache to ensure there's not any stale
> data
> success copy gatsby files — 0.044 s
> success onPreBootstrap — 0.039 s
> success source and transform nodes — 0.026 s
> success building schema — 0.112 s
> success createLayouts — 0.007 s
> success createPages — 0.001 s
> success createPagesStatefully — 0.082 s
> success onPreExtractQueries — 0.001 s
> success update schema — 0.072 s
> success extract queries from components — 0.041 s
> success run graphql queries — 0.015 s
> success write out page data — 0.005 s
> success write out redirect data — 0.001 s
> success onPostBootstrap — 0.001 s
>
> info bootstrap finished - 3.516 s
>
> success Building CSS — 13.139 s
> success Building production JavaScript bundles — 26.757 s
> ⢀ Building static HTML for pages{ API_URL: 
> 'https://api.company.com/api/company/prod',
>   COMPANY_URL: 'https://company.test.com/prod/',
>   NODE_ENV: 'production',
>   PUBLIC_DIR: 'D:\\website/public' }
> success Building static HTML for pages — 8.390 s
> info Done building in 51.808 sec
> ```

Comment: I have the same issue :-( I since I am a linux user cross-env is not a solution.

Comment: how did you print the URL after Building static HTML for pages ?

Answer (score 0):

i resolved this issue using cross-env package. Now it is working fine.

Here is the command

> "build:staging": "cross-env ACTIVE_ENV=\"staging\" gatsby build",

Now when i run `npm run build:staging` it build using .env.staging